# how to bind Combo Box using Stored Procedure in WPF & Entity Framework

Tags: combobox, binding, procedure, using

I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetFreeRooms
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [RoomId] 
    FROM [dbo].[tblRooms] 
    WHERE [RoomId] NOT IN (SELECT [RoomId] 
                           FROM [dbo].[tblRoomsAndLevels] 
                           WHERE [TermId] = (SELECT MAX([TermId]) 
                                             FROM [dbo].[tblTerms]))
END
```

How can I bind combo box using it?

i use this code C#

```
dpRooms.ItemsSource = dbs.GetFreeRooms();
//dbs is my entity model
dpRooms.DisplayMemberPath = "RoomId";
```

and this on xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="dpRooms" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="RoomId" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

if i can't using this way, tell me entity query of this .please.

*Sorry I can't speak English very well.*

Comment: Typically, for a combo box, you'd return at least **two** pieces of information - the internal `RoomId` as the value to store later on, but also *additionally* some kind of a human-readable **name** or **description** of the "thing" you're showing in the combobox.

Comment: any body aren't here.